# How to import class of one file to another in a subfolder in Java using vscode

Tags: java, class, package

```
import mytest.Mypckg;

public class Learn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Mypckg.show();
  }
}
```

```java
package mytest;
public class Mypckg {
  public static void show(){
    System.out.println("Good Moring");
  }
}
```

Both file are in same subfolder name mytest
but when I try to run main file => Learn, I am getting an error
"Learn.java:2: error: cannot find symbolimport mytest.Mypckg;". I have also tried by removing import mytest.Mypckg from Learn file as both are having same package but when I compile I am getting an error as  "cannot find symbol Mypckg".

Comment: Move `Learn` is a new subfolder `Mypckg` in folder `mytest`. The directory structure has to replicate the package structure. You may also need to rename the subpackage `Mypckg` to something not equal to the class's `Mypckg`s name since it may result in a name clash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right in one case that I have not mentioned  package mytest in main file (Learn.java). that's my bad but in my computer when I mentioned package mytest in both file then also I was getting an error like "cannot find symbol import  mytest.Mypckg;"
[image]

Finally I found the solution. The actual problem was I was using compiling method inside the subfolder mytest. Infact I tried to compile the file by going outside the subfolder to get the path for mytest folder. But the main culprit was something else.I was not using the class path (i.e -cp) in my compilation code. So to compile the package file in vscode we have to go to parent folder & type the following code.

```
javac -cp . mytest/Learn.java // compiler code with file path
```

And also to run the file we have to use

```
java mytest.Learn     // mytest is a subfolder (package folder) and learn is a main file
```

Here Below I have attached the image  for better clarification for my fellow colleagues. I hope my answer will help someone who wants to compile java code with package in vscode
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that both the files are in the package/folder named `mytest`
and your code seems to miss this line added below

```
package mytest;//added line
//import mytest.Mypckg;

public class Learn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Mypckg.show();
  }
}
```